# Failure to display the video file (base64) in the video tag

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, base64

I wrote an echo server with sockets

- In this way, the user selects a video file and it is sent to the
  server socket(as `base64`)
- The video file is echoed from the server side and displayed on the
  client-side
- The video file echoes correctly from the server side and I see it in the log

```
data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAGlzb21tcDQyAALjFG1vb3YAAABsbXZoZAAAAADc1axf3NWsXwAAPAAAc3CAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMAAYQkdHJhawAAAFx0a2hkAAAAA9zVrF...
```

when I put this video file(`base64 dataurl`) in the src of the video tag, `dataurl` is correctly placed in `src`,
and the video is dispayed correctly in chrome browser but the video is not displayed in firefox

And I get this `error` in firefox

```
Invalid URI. Load of media resource data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAGlzb21tcDQyAALjFG1vb3YAAABsbXZoZAAAAADc1axf3NWsXwAAPAAAc3CAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMAAYQkdHJhawAAAFx0a2hkAAAAA9zVrF...
```

My code:

```js
//start websocket define
var socket = new WebSocket(
  'ws://' + window.location.host +
  '/ws/');
// end websocket define

// upload video
let upload_video = document.querySelector('.upload-video')
let vid = document.querySelector('.vid');
upload_video.addEventListener("change", function() {
  file = this.files[0];
  showVideo(file);
});
let showVideo = (file) => {
  console.log(file)
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    let fileURL = fileReader.result;
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
      'message': fileURL,
      'file': 'video'
    }))
  }
}
// end of upload video


socket.onmessage = function(e) {
  var message = e.data;
  let object = JSON.parse(message);
  if (object.video) {
    console.log(object.video)
    vid.setAttribute('src', object.video);
  }
};

socket.onclose = function(e) {
  console.error('Socket closed unexpectedly');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Echo Bytes</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="" id="" class="upload-video">
    <video controls="" class='vid'></video>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```